# Sprite not moving properly Java

Tags: java, image, rendering

I am trying to make a Space Shooter using java, but it isn't working. I am currently working on spawning the enemies. To hold the positions of all the enemies, I used an `ArrayList` called `allEnemies`. The `ArrayList` is filled with `Point` objects. I am updating the Game by calling `updateEnemies()` in my game loop.

Originally, I had the enemy's y position increment by 1, but that was too fast, so I changed it to 0.2 in an attempt to slow it down. Once I made it 0.2, the sprites spawned at the top but didn't move down. I works for any value above 1, including decimals, but not anything below. Here is my code:

Enemy.java

```
package main;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Enemy {

    static ArrayList<Point> allEnemies = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public static ArrayList<Point> createEnemies(int round) {
        for (int i = 0; i < round; i++) {
            Point newEnemyLocation = new Point((int) (Math.random()*Game.WIDTH - 64), 0);
            allEnemies.add(newEnemyLocation);
        }
        return allEnemies; 
    }

    public static ArrayList<Point> updateEnemies() {
        if (allEnemies.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < allEnemies.size(); i++) {
                Point enemyLocation = allEnemies.get(i);
                if (enemyLocation.y <= Game.HEIGHT) {
                    allEnemies.get(i).y += 0.2;
                } else {
                    allEnemies.remove(i);
                }   
            }
        }
        return allEnemies;
    }

}
```

Game.java

```
package main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    //declare values
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final String TITLE = "Space Shooter";

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    private Player player;

    private BufferedImage playerImage;
    private BufferedImage bulletImage;
    private BufferedImage enemyImage;

    int playerx;
    int playery;

    int round = 1;

    public Game() {
        //
        player = new Player((WIDTH/2)-32, HEIGHT-200); 

        //allocates all file resources
        try {
            playerImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/player.png"));
            bulletImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/bullet.png"));
            enemyImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/enemy.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    //starts thread
    private synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    //stops thread
    private synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;

        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

    @Override
    //game loop
    public void run() {     
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns  = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta > 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            Shoot.updateBullets();
            Enemy.updateEnemies();
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " TICKS, " + frames + " FPS");
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop(); 
    }

    //updates sprite locations
    public void tick() {
        playerx = player.getX();
        playery = player.getY(); 
    }

    //renders sprites
    public void render() {
        //setting up triple-buffering
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g  = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //////////////////////////////////

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(playerImage, playerx, playery, this); 

        if (Shoot.allBullets.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++) {
                int bulletx = (int) Shoot.allBullets.get(i).getX();
                int bullety = (int) Shoot.allBullets.get(i).getY(); 
                g.drawImage(bulletImage, bulletx + 21, bullety, this);
            }
        }

        if (Enemy.allEnemies.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); i++) {
                int enemyx = (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(i).getX();
                int enemyy = (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(i).getY();
                g.drawImage(enemyImage, enemyx, enemyy, this);
            }
        } else {
            Enemy.createEnemies(round);
            round++;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            Shoot.addBullet(player.getX(), player.getY());
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            player.setY(playery -= 20);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            player.setY(playery += 20);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            player.setX(playerx += 20);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            player.setX(playerx -= 20);
        } 
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);

        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        game.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to be specific about what the problem is...

Comment: The problem is that when i set the enemy sprite to increment at a speed of less than 1, it doesnt move at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello it is because the point class holds 2 integers x and y and you are trying to add 0.2 to a integer that only can store values without decimals so you have 2 options 1 is to change the point to a Point2D (holds doubles and a double can hold numbers with decimals) or you could create a enemy class with a x and y float/double but in this case I would go for option 1 because this is a small game, good luck!

Edit:
I was wrong about point2d, just saw that it is a abstract class so do like this

public class Enemy{

public double x,y;

Public Enemy(double x, double y){

```
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
```

}

}

And use that as the object in your arraylist

Comment: I tried this out, but then certain parts of the code wouldn't function properly. Is there any way I could slow down the speed of the enemies without doing that?

Comment: @the fool okay then I would go for making a class with 2 doubles (x and y) and a constructor that takes 2 variables (x,y) then set the variables in the constructor by this.x =x; and same for y then use this class you just made as the object in the arraylist instead of point